# Word of Hexadecimal Value in Python

Tags: python, hex

Crucial terminology aside, the word value of `0xFF20` is `-224`. From `int( 'FF20', 16 )` I get `65312`.

Considering the high-level nature of the language, what is the method for getting the "word" value of a hex string in Python?

Comment: You want the signed value, you mean?

Comment: For lack of a better term, yes!

Comment: @AndrewBestic, it's the [best term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the signed value, like Pantashu mentioned, then you could use `ctypes`

```
ctypes.c_short(int('FF20', 16)).value
```

Comment: @Patashu, Whoops my bad!  That's what I get for not simply copying your name :)

Comment: Your answer is good if you know how long the hexidecimal string is going to be in advance (so you can use the right ctype). Otherwise it gets messy.

Comment: @Patashu Yes, very true.  And I guess he was being non-technical in his usage of the term `word`, but I automatically associated it with a 16-bit data type.  So unless the hex values lie within a known range, your mathematical approach is definitely better.

Comment: I'm hardware knowledge deficient, but I thought word size varied based on architecture.

Comment: For now two hexadecimal bytes is all that needs calculation. Thank you!

Comment: @Patashu Yep, it is.  Like I said, I just immediately associate word with unsigned short in my head.  Quite irrelevant here though.  Oh well.

Comment: You're lucky I'm not using Python on arbitrary processing architecture ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If the first character has its high bit set (8-F), then subtract the value 0x1000... (number of 0s equal to the number of hexidecimal characters in the word) from your value after parsing it.

e.g. FF20 has its high bit set, convert it to decimal and subtract 0x10000 from it (65536 - 65312 = -224)

You can compute the value 0x100... by computing 2 to the power of 4*number of hexidecimal characters in word. e.g. 2^(4*4) = 65536

Comment: I used `if ( HexValue[0:1] > 7 ):` and it works great, thanks